# PHP - Getting The Result From An API (CURL)

Tags: php, python, api, curl

I am trying to return the result from an API but it gives me an authentication failed message rather than the result i need.

I am using the novaexchange API which offers a Python example on this page:

https://novaexchange.com/remote/faq/

This is the current code i have ported to PHP:

```
function get_private_data($method) {
    $apikey = 'key_here';
    $apisecret = 'secret_here'; // signature
    $nonce = time();
    $uri = 'https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/private/' . $method . '/?nonce=' . $nonce;
    $sign = hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'apikey: ' . $apikey, 'signature: ' . $sign));
    $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($execResult);
    return $obj;
    curl_close($ch);
}

echo get_private_data('getbalances'); // BROKEN
```

How can i get the code working?

Edit: Trying with Post i get an error also:

```
function get_private_data($method) {
    $apikey = 'key_here';
    $apisecret = 'secret_here'; // signature
    $nonce = time();
    $uri = 'https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/private/' . $method . '/?nonce=' . $nonce;
    $sign = hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);

    $fields = array(
        'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'apikey' => $apikey,
        'signature' => $sign
    );

    $ch = curl_init($uri);

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
    //$obj = json_decode($execResult);
    //return $obj;
    return $execResult;
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the api_key and signature needs to be part of the post parameters, not the header. And it needs to be requested via POST, not GET.

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

Comment: Thanks @aynber and patrick, i have tried making a post request instead but also get the {"status": "error", "message": "Auth failed"} error still. I have edited my post with the new code, any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The `content-type` does need to be in the headers, not the post fields.

Comment: It also looks like they base64encode the hmac.

Comment: Thanks everyone i got it working now, also set raw output on the hash_hmac function and it works ok